# angular 8 with RxJs Invoking api calls on click event - Detaches if api server is down

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot, rxjs

I have a form with save button which invokes a spring boot microservices call. The application is built using angular 8 and RxJs.
I was trying to test what happens to the application just in case the Rest api server is down.

When Rest api is up and running ,  the button click works fine but when i try to suspend the rest api and invoke click i'm able to handle the error and show a notification in the UI but when i  restart the service (running condition) and click the save  button it does not work . I mean it's silent without any response. Does this mean the event is detached ?. How do i resolve it ?.

The form is a simple form with two input parameters .

Comment: I'm guessing that the first error terminates the stream. Would be easier if you showed the code, though.

Answer (score 0):

In your stream, make sure that your catchError is returning an observable.  The other option MIGHT be to change the pipe->map to a pipe->switchMap so that the failed response doesn't cancel your stream.

We would need to see your code to be able to help you beyond guesses.

Comment: Sure, yes i agree code would help. Since its client code im unable to paste the code but ill find a way to mimic the same with similar example and will post it soon.